# What service to use to deploy an Angular 17 app with SSR enabled on AWS?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, serverless

What is the most convenient way to deploy an app SSR app on AWS?

I saw that people are using AWS Amplify, Serverless and AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but what is the best to do for a large Angular 17 app with SSR?

Angular 17 is new so did not find much regarding any of its deployments.

Comment: Did you find any solutions? There's zero guidance on this from both angular and aws team. It's so frustrating. Where should i deploy angular 17? How should I deploy angular 17? hmm

Comment: Didn't find something worth sharing here. Will update if anything comes up